# Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions -Dropwizard with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, jpa, dropwizard

I am using Hibernate and JPA in my dropwizard application to help with the CRUD operatons of my objects. Here is the method that throws the exception

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 5,
      types = {org.hibernate.exception.LockTimeoutException.class,
          org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException.class},
      delay = DATABASE_RETRY_DELAY_SECONDS, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  public MyObject createOrSave(MyObject myObject) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();



    session.beginTransaction();
    try {

      session.saveOrUpdate(service);
      session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

      session.getTransaction().rollback();
      throw e;
    } finally {

      if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();
      }
    }
    return myObject;
  }
```

There are many threads on SO that address this issue, the things I've tried so far

- Check if the session is open , if yes use `session.getCurrentSession()`, this throws an error that a "`transaction is already active`"
- Dont use transaction at all
- Check if record exists in the database , if yes use `session.merge()` else `session.save()`
- In my relationships dont use `CascadeType.ALL`, but this resulted in a "`trying to refernece transient object error`"

I am out of ideas, any ideas?

Looking more into this, it appears that the problem is with a relationship with an Element collection on MyObject which is declared as

```
  @JsonIgnore
  @Column
  @ElementCollection(targetClass = Long.class)
  Set<Long> someLongIds;
```

Is there any other way to declare this so it can be modified when myObject is saved or updated ?

So I changed the mapping to

```
      @JsonIgnore
      @Column
      @ElementCollection(targetClass = Long.class, fetch = fetchType.Lazy)
      Set<Long> someLongIds;
```

This got rid of the error for this specific mapping but I still get the

```
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection
```

error on all the other mappings on the Object.

is this because the collection is a Set? and not threadsafe?

Comment: Is there a reason you try to manage the session yourself? Unless there isn't a specific reason for it I would let it be managed...

Comment: I have run into too many open sessions issue so I manually open and close them in my transactions

Comment: How does that solve the issue that you have too many open sessions? The only difference I see is that in your implementation you don't reuse the existing sessions. Somehow the collection you are trying to save is linked to another session that is still open. I would guess the one you used to fetch it initially but that information is mission from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are two open Sessions in Hibernate, and MyObject is being passed from one to the other.

The simplest solution normally is to use the same `Session`.  If working with JTA transactions (or any other form of [contextual sessions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html#architecture-current-session) in Hibernate), this can be found by calling `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.  Clearly this wouldn't be workable in a multi-threaded environment though.

The other route would be to detach `myObject`.  Back in the first Session (not shown in the question), when `myObject` was retrieved from the database, it can also be detached from that session:

```
session.detach(myObject);
```

This has the effect of resolving the `PersistentSet` of `someLongIds` so they can be accessed outside the Session, or equally in another Session.

Comment: I think from my nderstanding, the error is thrown for an object that is transitively updated as a result of cascading , do you mean this object should be detached ? Can you help understanding with pseudo code?

Comment: there are many sessions that probably update the objects transitively , should the objects be detached in every session?